# macports texlive can't find .sty file

Tags: packages, texlive, macports

I have `texlive-fonts-extra` installed:

```
$ port installed texlive-fonts-extra
The following ports are currently installed:
  texlive-fonts-extra @22691_0+doc (active)
```

According to https://trac.macports.org/wiki/TeXLivePackages, `texlive-fonts-extra` has `doublestroke`

However, while compiling (`$ pdflatex article.tex`) a .tex file containing

```
\usepackage{mathtools, doublestroke}
```

I get

```
! LaTeX Error: File `doublestroke.sty' not found.
```

I am using the correct copy of latex since

```
$ which pdflatex
/opt/local/bin/pdflatex
```

What should I do to troubleshoot?

Comment: There is *no* `doublestroke.sty` package. The name to use is `dsfont`

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a `doublestroke` package. According to the [documentation for doublestroke](http://mirror.ox.ac.uk/sites/ctan.org/fonts/doublestroke/dsdoc.pdf) you need

`\usepackage{dsfont}`

Alternatively, you can access the font as follows, but the package is the better option.

```
\documentclass{article}
\font\dsrom=dsrom10 
\begin{document}
\[\hbox{\dsrom N}=\{0,1,2,\ldots\}\]
\[\hbox{\dsrom ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ}\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: The usage of `\font` in LaTeX is highly discouraged. Would you consider removing that part?

Comment: @egreg --- I posted too quickly, in a failed effort to get there before you! I have corrected my answer.

Comment: I had TeX Live Utility running. :)